Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException error when json generated on .NET 8 and consumed in .NET 4.8
I am having trouble passing data between 2 processes that are using different .NET versions (.NET 8 and .NET 4.8).
The nature of the data is such that the data type is define as 'object' so that different data can be passed in different cases (this is something I cannot change). I need to use the serialization options ensure that type information is passed with the JSON.
Simple example of the problem, build using VS2022 and using Newtonsoft v13.0.3.
This raises an exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error resolving type specified in JSON 'System.Double[], System.Private.CoreLib'.
JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib'.

TestData (.NET Standard 2.0)
using System;    

namespace Data
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class TestData
    {
        public object[] data;
    }
}

WriteJson (.NET 8)
namespace WriteJson
{
    using Data;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testData = new TestData()
            {
                data = new object[]
                {
                    new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 },
                    new[] { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 },
                }
            };

            var serSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
            };

            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serSettings);
            var fileName = @"C:\TEMP\TestData.json";

            using (var fs = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
            using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(fs))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, testData);
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();;
            }
        }
    }
}

ReadJson (.NET 4.8)
namespace ReadJson
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.IO;
    using Data;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };
            var fileName = @"C:\TEMP\TestData.json";

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
                var result = (TestData)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(TestData));
            }
        }
    }
}

JSON
{
    "data":
        [
            { 
               "$type": "System.Double[], System.Private.CoreLib",
               "$values": [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ]
            },
            {
               "$type": "System.Double[], System.Private.CoreLib",
               "$values": [ 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 ]
            }
        ]
}

I would hope to be able to serialize/deserialize between the different versions of .NET but I get the exception presumably because System.Private.CoreLib which contains the type in .NET 8 is not understood by .NET 4.8.
Currently I have resorted to parsing the JSON line by line and doing a similar substitution. This is obviously inefficient and I need to remember to generate the JSON in indented format. What I think I need is an equivalent to the SerializationBinder mentioned in .Net Standard 4.7.1 Could not load System.Private.CoreLib during serialization, but operates at Deserialization.

I get the exception presumably because System.Provate.CoreLib which contains the type in net8 is not understood by net48 -- that is exactly correct.  You will need to write a custom SerializationBinder.  To do that, see this answer by Andrii Litvinov to .Net Standard 4.7.1 Could not load System.Private.CoreLib during serialization.  Does that answer your question?

That certainly works when the framework of the des-erializer is known because it acts at serialization; but what I really want is to cope with the same json being de-serialized by either framework

If you also need to go from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8 and so the linked duplicate isn't sufficient to meet your needs, could you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically samples of both formats of JSON you need to deserialize on either platforms?

If you can share a [mcve] with both types of JSON we can get this reopened and an answer provided.  Thanks!

I have resorted to parsing the JSON line by line and doing a similar substitution. This is obviously inefficient and I need to remember to generate the JSON in indented format.
What I think I need is an equivalent to the SerializationBinder mentioned above, but operates at Deserialization. That would be my updated question.
